# Modeh Ani - When to say the blessing

Tags: tefilla, blessing, sleep, morning-day

When is the proper time to say the *Modeh Ani* blessing? Sometimes people wake up at 4 or 5 am to use the bathroom and then go back to sleep. Is it correct to say the blessing only when waking up for the final time, just before *netilat yadayim*, or should it be said each time one wakes up in the night? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! We [try to avoid practical halacha questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).  I've [edited](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/47949/edit) this one for you.  We hope to see you around!

Comment: @dror Since Modeh Ani does not contain the name of Hashem, it is not a bracha which would ordinarily be said before (or after) performing a mitzvah. It is a declaration of gratitude towards Hashem for restoring your soul for a new day. This reference implies http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1466224/jewish/Modeh-Ani.htm implies that Modeh Ani is said when immediately one first wakes up while still in bed. However, it is said once you are intent to start your day and go about your daily business. It seems to suggest getting up to go to the bathroom (men sometimes have to do it....

Comment: ...several times a night) does not fulfill the concept of intent to start your day. Now what happens if you can't fall asleep? How long do you lay awake in bed before realizing you are not going to fall back to sleep? Well, that's a different issue....

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51096/5323

Answer (score 7):

[Rabbi Binyamin Shmueli](http://www.hidabroot.org/he/question/17448) and [Rabbi Eliezer Altshuler](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/169494-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%99) concur that one does not say Modeh Ani when waking up and returning to sleep, one only says it the final time they wake up in the morning.

Answer (score -1):

Only the final time you wake up in the morning.

Comment: Hello user 7435, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! [edit]ing your answer to include a source for your claim would greatly improve it. Also, you should consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. You might also think about giving yourself a more imaginative name than "user7435," unless that's your favorite number ;-) Hope to see you around!