# Morning blessings when going back to sleep

Tags: halacha, blessing, rambam, sleep

I recite the birchot ha-shachar according to the Rambam, which is to say the first thing I say in the morning is elohai neshama, then I sit up and say matir asurim, etc. If I get up early in the morning to do some task, but then go back to bed and wake up later, do should I bless again on things I've already done once that day?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47949/5323

Answer (score 4):

Well, the Rambam you refer to in [הלכות תפילה וברכת כהנים - פרק שביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) says:

> **ג:**  בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁיִּיקַץ **בְּסוֹף שְׁנָתוֹ** מְבָרֵךְ וְהוּא עַל מִטָּתוֹ כָּךְ. אֱ-לֹקי נְשָׁמָה שֶׁנָּתַתָּ בִּי טְהוֹרָה  ‏

To which the Kesef Mishne comments:

> **בשעה שייקץ בסוף שנתו**. כלומר דאף על גב דאמרינן בגמרא ([ברכות דף ס':](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00878.html#HtmpReportNum0117_L2)) כי מתער לימא אלהי נשמה וכו' אין הכוונה כל זמן שייקץ באי זו שעה שתהיה אלא **דוקא בסוף שנתו**.

So the correct procedure, according to the Rambam, seems to be, that when you're done sleeping for the night, **then** you say the Brachot.

So, if you get up early in the morning to do some task, you should not make the Brachot, if you then go back to bed and wake up later. Ther last time you get out of bed you should say them.