# Modeh Ani - naps?

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, sleep, children

I started saying Modeh Ani with my daughter every morning which is great. 
She's a baby and she takes a few naps a day.

Should I say it Every time she wakes up or just in the morning?

Comment: Rebecca, a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting so many interesting questions! Please note that "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but *[does not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)." So, questions along the lines of "Should I ..." are not ones Mi Yodeya can answer for you. I recommend [edit]ing this post to be asking for general information.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47949/modeh-ani-when-to-say-the-blessing

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I am fairly sure we say Modeh Ani whenever we awake, not just in the morning. And we always wash our hands. At least that's how I was taught.

We should always thank Hashem whenever he restores our soul.

Comment: The Arukh HaShulhan writes that it is not customary to wash hands upon awaking after naps.

Comment: I don't think that the practice of Modeh Ani was originally meant for naps. However, it is not a halakhic requirement, with technical parameters, but a mere custom. You can say it whenever you find it meaningful.

Comment: @mevaqesh - I always have washed my hands after naps but maybe that's just an act of Chassidus...I never knew it said that in the Aruch HaShulchan.

Comment: Regarding saying *Modeh Ani* in the morning, note that "רבה אמונתך" is a reference to [*Eicha* 3:23](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3203.htm#23).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the minhag is only to say modeh ani upon waking in the morning, not after subsequent naps.

Comment: `If the afternoon nap is long, we wash our hands without a bracha` The Arukh HaShulhan writes that it is not customary to wash hands upon awaking after naps

Comment: @mevaqesh -  Thank you, I did not know that. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I add the disclaimer that I referenced it form memory.

Comment: What I'm getting is that there's nothing wrong with saying it every time so we're going to go ahead and keep it up! I want our baby to hear as much Hebrew as possible and repeating regular blessings daily establishes a strong connection to Ha Shem.

Answer (score 0):

You only say modeh ani when you wake up in the morning. Its a good sentiment to have when waking up, but you don't have to say that specific tefillah. You do, however, wash negel vasser if you sleep for more than 30 minutes. Don't know how that would fly with a baby tho.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first wave of answers. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!